# Efficiently adding multiple items to a list/collection after creation VB.net without an add line for each item

Tags: vb.net, list

I'd like to add multiple items to a created list **after** creation without putting a .add line for each item or looping through with a for loop.

Example if I wanted to set at creation:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String) From { "string1", "string2", "string3" }
```

Example if I used a .add line for each item:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)
list. Add("string1")
list. Add("string2")
list. Add("string2")
```

Example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)
list. Add({ "string1", "string2", "string3" })
```

or

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)
list. Add FROM { "string1", "string2", "string3" }
```

If this isn't feasible let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `AddRange` method is what you want. You could have found that by reading the documentation for the `List(Of T)` class. ALWAYS read the documentation first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String) From { "string1", "string2", "string3" }
```

Here's some [documentation on Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/collection-initializers/).

It's better than the existing answer, because the existing answer creates an actual array with its own separate memory, and then adds the array to the list. The loop is still there, it's just hidden by the `AddRange()` method. This collection initializer syntax also just hides the loop, but at least the extra array object is saved.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to jmcilhinney's answer in the comments!

Reiterating, this can be achieved using the `list.AddRange` method

Example:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)
list.AddRange({ "string1", "string2", "string3" })
```

I agree, I should have searched through the documentation better, but now this will forever exist for the google searcher!